# Loop through headers in CSV file and make shapefiles from each header

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, csv, loop

I am unable to figure a way out how to create a shapefile after looping through the csv files and matching the headers (dates in format Oct11/2018). Each shapefile should have all the fields with the date that matches the header. In this way I want to create multiple shapefiles for each single date and with the date as the name of the shapefile.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import csv
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/gst_airtemp/excels_shapefiles"
path = "D:/datasets/regression_interpolation_rasters/gst_airtemp/excels_shapefiles"
#arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
scratchGDB = arcpy.env.scratchGDB
csvlist = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

headers_dict = dict()
for filename in all_csv:
    #print(filename)##15
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col= None, header=0, parse_dates = True, usecols=lambda x: x not in ["Stat_name","Name", "Altitude", "Lat", "Long"])
    #print(df)
    #print(type(df))
    headers_dict[filename] = df.columns
    #print(type(headers_dict))

for csvfile in csvlist:
    #print(csvfile)##24
    headers = pd.read_csv(csvfile, index_col= None, header=0, parse_dates = True, usecols=lambda x: x not in ["Stat_name","Name", "Altitude", "Lat", "Long"])
    #print(headers)
    #print(type(headers))

    
    headers_dict = headers
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(csvfile, scratchGDB, "CSV")
    outLayer = "date"
    #print(table)
    #print(type(table))
    spatialreference = arcpy.SpatialReference(32632)
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(os.path.join(scratchGDB, "CSV"), "Long","Lat",outLayer,spatialreference,"Altitude")
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(outLayer, path) 
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outLayer, "outLayer_lyr") 
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("outLayer_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION")
```

Here is one example using an image

This is the csv file converted to shapefile with all the dates
[image]

Converted shapefile I want

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?  When testing/presenting code I think you should always remove any try/except statements because they can mask otherwise useful error messages.

Comment: the code is still incomplete, in the last part I am still trying to figure out a way where the list of dates in dictionary matches the headers in the csv files, if they do make a shapefile for that date along with lat, long and altitude.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.